# How to convert 2D point to 3D using SceneKit's unprojectPoint without having a depth value?

Tags: ios, 3d, scenekit

Is it possible to use SceneKit's [unprojectPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925879/how-do-i-find-my-mouse-point-in-a-scene-using-scenekit) to convert a 2D point to 3D without having a depth value?
I only need to find the 3D location in the XZ plane. Y can be always 0 or any value since I'm not using it.

I'm trying to do this for iOS 8 Beta.

I had something similar with JavaScript and Three.js (WebGL) like this:

```
function getMouse3D(x, y) {
    var pos = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    var pMouse = new THREE.Vector3(
        (x / renderer.domElement.width) * 2 - 1,
       -(y / renderer.domElement.height) * 2 + 1,
       1
    );
    //
    projector.unprojectVector(pMouse, camera);

    var cam = camera.position;
    var m = pMouse.y / ( pMouse.y - cam.y );

    pos.x = pMouse.x + ( cam.x - pMouse.x ) * m;
    pos.z = pMouse.z + ( cam.z - pMouse.z ) * m;

    return pos;
};
```

But I don't know how to translate the part with unprojectVector to SceneKit.

---

What I want to do is to be able to drag an object around in the XZ plane only. The vertical axis Y will be ignored.

Since the object would need to move along a plane, one solution would be to use hitTest method, but I don't think is very good in terms of performance to do it for every touch/drag event. Also, it wouldn't allow the object to move outside the plane either.

I've tried a solution based on the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925879/how-do-i-find-my-mouse-point-in-a-scene-using-scenekit), but it didn't worked. Using one depth value for unprojectPoint, if dragging the object around in the +/-Z direction the object doesn't stay under the finger too long, but it moves away from it instead.
I need to have the dragged object stay under the finger no matter where is it moved in the XZ plane.

Answer (score 2):

First, are you actually looking for a position in the xz-plane or the xy-plane? By default, the camera looks in the -z direction, so the x- and y-axes of the 3D Scene Kit coordinate system go in the same directions as they do in the 2D view coordinate system. (Well, y is flipped by default in UIKit, but it's still the vertical axis.) The xz-plane is then orthogonal to the plane of the screen.

Second, a depth value is a necessary part of converting from 2D to 3D. I'm not an expert on three.js, but from looking at their [library documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/) (which apparently can't be linked into), their `unprojectVector` still takes a `Vector3`. And that's what you're constructing for `pMouse` in your code above — a vector whose z- and y-coordinates come from the 2D mouse position, and whose z-coordinate is 1.

SceneKit's [`unprojectPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRenderer_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SCNSceneRenderer/unprojectPoint%3a) works the same way — it takes a point whose z-coordinate refers to a depth in [clip space](http://www.gamerendering.com/2008/10/05/clip-space/), and maps that to a point in your scene's world space.

If your world space is oriented such that the only variation you care about is in the x- and y-axes, you may pass any z-value you want to `unprojectPoint`, and ignore the z-value in the vector you get back. Otherwise, pass `-1` to map to the far clipping plane, `1` for the near clipping plane, or `0` for halfway in between — the plane whose z-coordinate (in camera space) is `0`. If you're using the unprojected point to position a node in the scene, the best advice is to just try different z-values (between -1 and 1) until you get the behavior you want.

However, it's a good idea to be thinking about what you're using an unprojected vector for — if the next thing you'd be doing with it is testing for intersections with scene geometry, look at [hitTest:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRenderer_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SCNSceneRenderer/hitTest%3aoptions%3a) instead.

Comment: Please look at my answer to see what I'm trying to do.