# Get SCNVector3 from CGPoint

Tags: objective-c, xcode, scenekit

I am trying to get a SCNVector3 from a CGPoint. I am using a gesture recognizer to get the location of a touch (as a CGPoint).

The problem is that the touch doesn't always hit something when I hit test because there isn't always an object being touched. (Touch an empty space to move your ship to that empty spot).

Other Stack Overflow question that I have found uses the SCNHitTestResult to get the `worldCoordinates` but that doesn't work for me.

Does anyone know how to find this? Given that I know the z coordinate of course. Ships that move always move with a z position of 1.

I Need worldCoordinates to be able to use actions that move a SCNNode to a touch point which has a CGPoint. Thanks!

Comment: Is [this the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925879/how-do-i-find-my-mouse-point-in-a-scene-using-scenekit/22944797#22944797) you're talking about? Read between the lines there and you'll find a solution. Or wait a couple minutes and I'll finish posting a more specific answer here.

Answer (score 9):

So, you want to turn a point in view space into a point in scene space? The catch to that, of course, is that scene space has a third dimension and view space doesn't. You use the `SCNView` (or other renderer) methods [`projectPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRenderer_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SCNSceneRenderer/projectPoint:) and [`unprojectPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRenderer_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SCNSceneRenderer/unprojectPoint:) to convert between scene space, which is 3D, and view space, which is... also 3D? Yep — two dimensions of screen <strike>pixels</strike>points, and one of normalized depth: the z-coordinate is 0 for points on the near clipping plane and 1 for points on the far clipping plane.

Anyhow, you have a useful constraint in that you're looking to map view-space points onto a specific plane (`z=1`) in scene space. You have an even more useful constraint if your scene space is oriented so that said plane is orthogonal to the view direction — i.e. the camera is pointing directly in the +z or -z direction.

If you want to map a view-space point to a particular scene-space depth, you need to know what the view-space depth for that plane is. Use `projectPoint` for that:

```
SCNVector3 projectedPlaneCenter = [view projectPoint:planeNode.position];
float projectedDepth = projectedPlaneCenter.z;
```

Now, hold onto that and you can make use of it whenever you need to map a touch location onto that plane:

```
CGPoint vp = [recognizer locationInView:view];
SCNVector3 vpWithDepth = SCNVector3Make(vp.x, vp.y, projectedDepth);
SCNVector3 scenePoint = [view unprojectPoint:vpWithDepth];
```

---

If your scene isn't oriented with the z-axis parallel to the camera, it's a bit harder — you have to work out where your `z=1` plane is independently for any view-space point you process. In that case, you might find it easier to add an invisible `SCNPlane` to your scene and use the `hitTest`/`worldCoordinates` method to locate points on that plane.

Comment: `is that scene space has a third dimension and scene space doesn't` => second `scene space` should be `view space` right?