# Convert CGPoint from a View to SCNVector3 in sceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, face-detection, scnvector3

I am using **AVFoundation** for front camera View. From the **Front camera**, I'm **detecting** the **Face** from each frame using vision framework. From that, I'm able to get **CGPoints of nose**. Now, I want to **add a 3D object** on one of the nose points using sceneKit view and I want to **convert those Nose CGPoint to SCNVector3** so that I can give the position to the 3D object.

Comment: Could be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26832208/get-scnvector3-from-cgpoint

Comment: @spads SCNVector3 taking x,y,z values in very small magnitude. For eg. Value of even 0.1 is making large displacement. The Link u have mentioned, is projecting the CGPoint, but even projection does'nt give the values of such small magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

Convert CGPoint to SCNVector in SceneKit either by hitTest or raycast method,

```
 let touchPoint = CGPoint(x: 34, y: 298) // for hitTest example
 let hitTestResult : [ARHitTestResult]  = sceneView.hitTest(touchPoint, types: .featurePoint)
     guard let hitResult = hitTestResult.first else {
       return
       }
 let vector = SCNVector3((hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.x), (hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.y), (hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.z))
        print(vector) // returns somewhat like this SCNVector3(x: -0.2502137, y: 0.15422173, z: -0.17789307)
```